# R internal memory allocation error handling

Tags: r, memory, allocation

I had a question regarding the triggering of the error when the memory allocation tries to exceed `memory.limit()` such as in

```
> test <- 1:1e10
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Reached total allocation of 3975Mb: see help(memory.size) 
2: Reached total allocation of 3975Mb: see help(memory.size) 
3: Reached total allocation of 3975Mb: see help(memory.size) 
4: Reached total allocation of 3975Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

My main question is how this error message is invoked? Is the memory allocation an event and R has an internal event listener or is some function called before the assignment of any variable to check the estimated memory usage? If the second is true, can you theoretically turn this function off?

---

Ad comments:

Sorry, I still don't get it. Where does the error come from, meaning what process is responsible for the error message? How does R know that an object exceeds the allocation and to return an error?
It seems to that there are two possibilities:

- R tries to create object - system (or some other processs) returns that allocation is not possible - R breaks execution and throws error -> This feels like an event handling
- R estimates `object.size(1:1e10)` by some internal functions and before the variable is created it calls a `stop(...)`

Please correct me if I got it all wrong!

---

Ad comments (Joshua Ulrich):

Okay, then how does R communicate with the memory?

Comment: It has nothing to do with assignment. You get the same error if you run `1:1e10`. You ask to create an object; R tries to allocate memory for that object and fails, yielding an error message. There's no estimation.

Comment: In addition , the failure to create the memory is `either because the size exceeded the address-space limit for a process or, more likely, because the system was unable to provide the memory`. You can read [this](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) for more details.

Comment: Regarding your additional comments: R is single-threaded, and it's responsible for the error message. R knows the object exceeds available memory because that's what the OS tells R when R asks for the memory. There's no "event handling", and (again), there's no estimation.